# MySQL Unknown Column, but column exists

Tags: php, mysql

Running the following MySQL Query and am getting this error:

> database error Unknown column 'qd.ItemListID' in 'on clause'

```
SELECT 
    IFNULL(hqp.IsActive, qd.ItemName) AS Item_Name, DATE_FORMAT(IFNULL(hqp.SalesDate, qd.SalesDate), '%m-%d-%Y') AS effectDate, IFNULL(hqp.NoBid, qd.NoBid) AS noBid, IFNULL(hqp.VendorName, qd.VendorName) AS vendor, IFNULL(hqp.Source, qd.Source) AS source, IFNULL(hqp.Type, qd.Type) AS type, IFNULL(hqp.Cost, qd.PurchaseCost) AS cost, IFNULL(hqp.Price, qd.SalesPrice) AS price, IFNULL(hqp.ConditionCode, '') AS conditionCode, qi.UnitOfMeasureSetRef_FullName AS uom
FROM wp_quantum_data AS qd, wp_hunter_quote_parts AS hqp
LEFT JOIN wp_quickbook_items AS qi ON (qi.ListID = IFNULL(qd.ItemListID, hqp.Item_ListID))
WHERE qd.IsActive = 1 || hqp.IsActive = 1
GROUP BY Item_Name
ORDER BY Item_Name ASC
```

The column exists in the `wp_quantum_data` table so I can't explain why this error is occurring.  I've tried renaming the column in phpmyadmin by typing the column name in and saving the column structure, but it is still saying that the column doesn't exist.

[image: wp_quantum_data]

Comment: Did you check if your case is correct? ItemListID, ItemListId, ...

Comment: Yes, the column name is set to `ItemListID`, and this is correct in the `wp_quantum_data` table, which I recently renamed from `wp_quickbook_vendor_items`.  could it have something to do with changing the name of the database table?  Which doesn't make sense to me either.

Comment: `LEFT JOIN wp_quickbook_items AS qi`, is there AS needed? I normally use without it.

Comment: @laser: `AS` is optional.

Comment: @JiriHrazdil `FROM wp_quantum_data AS qd, wp_hunter_quote_parts AS hqp` is it from two tables select?

Comment: @SolomonClosson: what happens when you execute the above query directly in phpMyAdmin/Adminer/mysql console?

Comment: @JiriHrazdil Yes, I need to grab from 2 tables, but need to prioritize the `wp_hunter_quote_parts` table over the `wp_quantum_data` table, which I'm doing inside of the selects.  Basically, if it's not found inside of the `wp_hunter_quote_parts` table, than I need to get it from the `wp_quantum_data` table (if found in there), so I need to select both tables for this, in order to be sure we get data to work with.

Comment: I get the same result in phpmyadmin:  `Unknown column 'qd.ItemListID' in 'on clause'`

Comment: @SolomonClosson but if your select takes a row from table `wp_hunter_quote_parts`, then `qd` is not defined for that row at all? and ItemListID is non existent? I cannot understand your query logic.

Comment: @SolomonClosson to avoid such complexities, I would prefer LEFT JOIN method

Comment: @SolomonClosson: does `ItemListID` column exist in table `wp_hunter_quote_parts` or `wp_quickbook_items`?

Comment: Problem with a Join method here is that if the FROM table is empty it won't return anything on the other table.  I need it to return from the other table, even if FROM table is an empty result.

Comment: `ItemListID` exists in `wp_quantum_data`, `Item_ListID` exists in `wp_hunter_quote_parts`, and `ListID` exists in `wp_quickbook_items`

Comment: @SolomonClosson can you use just JOIN? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12475850/how-can-an-sql-query-return-data-from-multiple-tables

Comment: Isn't that what I'm doing right now?

Comment: @SolomonClosson maybe it is best for you right now is to run EXPLAIN on your select.

Comment: Can you show me one example using ON in this way: `ON (qi.ListID = IFNULL(qd.ItemListID, hqp.Item_ListID))`  instead of `ON (qi.ListID = qd.ItemListID  OR qi.ListID = hqp.Item_ListID)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you're mixing the archaic implicit `JOIN` syntax with `LEFT JOIN`. The `LEFT JOIN` only combines with the table immediately before it, which is `wp_hunter_quote_parts`; you can't refer to columns in `wp_quantum_data` in the `ON` clause.

You should get out of the habit of using implicit joins, and use explicit `JOIN` clauses for everything.

You also seem to have your joins in the wrong order. Since the row can be missing in `wp_hunter_quote_parts`, that's the table you should `LEFT JOIN` with.

```
SELECT 
    IFNULL(hqp.IsActive, qd.ItemName) AS Item_Name, DATE_FORMAT(IFNULL(hqp.SalesDate, qd.SalesDate), '%m-%d-%Y') AS effectDate, IFNULL(hqp.NoBid, qd.NoBid) AS noBid, IFNULL(hqp.VendorName, qd.VendorName) AS vendor, IFNULL(hqp.Source, qd.Source) AS source, IFNULL(hqp.Type, qd.Type) AS type, IFNULL(hqp.Cost, qd.PurchaseCost) AS cost, IFNULL(hqp.Price, qd.SalesPrice) AS price, IFNULL(hqp.ConditionCode, '') AS conditionCode, qi.UnitOfMeasureSetRef_FullName AS uom
FROM wp_quantum_data AS qd
LEFT JOIN wp_quickbook_items AS qi ON qi.ListID = qd.ItemListID
LEFT JOIN wp_hunter_quote_parts AS hqp ON qi.ListID = hqp.ItemListID AND hqp.IsActive = 1
WHERE qd.IsActive = 1
GROUP BY Item_Name
ORDER BY Item_Name ASC
```

Comment: No, it is possible, that `wp_quickbook_items` will not have anything in it also.  So I need to account for that.

Comment: `wp_quantum_data` will most likely have the most results in it, since this is coming from an import of data.  `wp_hunter_quote_parts` is only getting populated when quotes are approved, so it will populate depending on approved status of quote.  These 2 tables are very identical and need to be merged so that I grab the new data (`wp_hunter_quote_parts`) when it is available ONLY, otherwise the old data (`wp_quantum_data`).  The addition of `wp_quickbook_items` is really only needed for getting the Unit of Measure (UOM) if exists.

Comment: OK, I changed `wp_quantum_data` to be the master table, with left joins to both other tables.

Comment: Is is possible that `wp_quantum_data` table will not have the Item in it also, as I don't want to store any new Items in this table.  New Items will go into the `wp_hunter_quote_parts` table.

Comment: So which table has the complete list of items?

Comment: You wrote above "if it's not found inside of the wp_hunter_quote_parts table, than I need to get it from the wp_quantum_data table". That's why I thought `wp_quantum_data` is the primary table.

Comment: Neither.  `wp_hunter_quote_parts` has new items, `wp_quantum_data` has imported/old items.  We need information from `wp_hunter_quote_parts` if exists, otherwise, grab from the `wp_quantum_data` if it exists in there.

Comment: It sounds like you need a `FULL OUTER JOIN`, but MySQL doesn't have that. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4796872/full-outer-join-in-mysql for the workarounds.

Comment: `wp_quantum_data` is only being used for historical purposes, but when the item gets put into the `wp_hunter_quote_parts` table, it now should override the historical data.